# How to make turtles move only in white blocks in the new model?

Tags: netlogo

kindly I need your support to check the below code for NetLogo as I always face the below picture when I display the (New model) when I press the Go button. All I want all turtles ONLY move inside these white blocks (Not outside as below ), so any advice? 
Thanks a lot

[image]

```
    to go
      if all? turtles [ happy? ] [ stop ]
      if ( Model = "New Model") [ ask turtles with [ not happy? ] [ move_other_area ] ]
      update-turtles
      update-globals
      tick
    end


    to move_other_area


      move-to one-of patches with [ (not any? other turtles-here) and (area != [area] of myself) ]

    end
```

Comment: In your `move-to` command, try adding `and pcolor = white`